# Best practices for encryption from web<-> specific client

Tags: authentication, key-management, key-exchange

If we want to allow sensitive data between a web server and specific client only, is there anything more that can be done besides the following?

Note that this is potentially a duplicate of [Authenticating client without hardcoding key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/authenticating-client-without-hardcoding-key) but the focus here is more on a good solution within this limitation (that there is no absolutely definitive solution to authenticate the client)

1) All traffic flows over SSL

2) Client has AES-256 key hardcoded yet obfuscated

3) Server has same AES-256 key

4) Client makes request for new "session key"

5) Server generates random session key and encrypts it with shared AES-key

6) Client decrypts, and all further exchange happens over this "session key" (which is also aes-256)

Comment: within what limitation? are the 6 steps the limitation or the thing you want to improve?

Comment: I'm also confused about why you are encrypting the data again within an SSL stream.

Comment: clarified - the problem is not so much man in the middle attacks but more someone decompiling the client and impersonating it

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a hardcoded key, you should use mutual SSL authentication. Using an obfuscated key, doesn't add any security, certainly not when you're already using SSL.

Comment: Oh interesting... not sure why nobody mentioned that in the linked question... I will investigate this. Thanks!

Comment: After looking- this seems to be identical to the above, only needlessly complex, because a private key must still be stored in the client for this to work.. and therefore it goes back to the problem of an impersonator.

Comment: Per client key. That's the best practice.